# Python dataclasses: What type to use if __post_init__ performs type conversion?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a Python class, with a field which can be passed one of several sequence types. To simplify I'll stick with tuples and lists. `__init__` converts the parameter to `MyList`.

```
from typing import Union
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, field

class MyList(list):
    pass

@dataclass
class Struct:
    field: Union[tuple, list, MyList]

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.field = MyList(self.field)
```

What type should I use for the `field` declaration?

- If I supply a union of all possible input types, the code does not document that `field` is always a `MyList` when *accessed*.
- If I only supply the final `MyList` type, PyCharm complains when I pass `Struct()` a `list`.

I could instead use:

```
_field: InitVar[Union[tuple, list, MyList]] = None
field: MyList = field(init=False)

def __post_init__(self, _field):
    self.field = MyList(_field)
```

but this is tremendously ugly, especially when repeated across 3 fields. Additionally I have to construct a struct like `Struct(_field=field)` instead of `Struct(field=field)`.

In April 2018, "tm" commented on this issue on PyCharm's announcement: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/04/python-37-introducing-data-class/#comment-323957

Comment: [This discussion on github](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/issues/60) touches on the issue of converters, which seems to me what you're asking for, and why they are not part of dataclasses. Your current implementation with `InitVar` is the intended solution for your scenario.

Comment: One of my use cases for converters is converting user input (via YAML files) to a type-safe enum for my configuration struct. Maybe I'll accomplish this using a function which wraps the constructor and converts the input. As for my other usecase of converting ndarray to MyArray, I'll have to review my code to find a solution I like.

Comment: I see. Well, one alternative would then be to switch to [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/), which supports converters.
And unrelated, but since you brought it up, `yaml.load` is unsafe for user input. Unless you can trust your users, you should use `yaml.safe_load`.

Comment: Oh yeah I use ruamel.yaml, I believe all loaders (including roundtrip) are safe except 'unsafe'.

Comment: *Just don't use a dataclass*.

Answer (score 7):

You are conflating assigning a value to the attribute with the code that *produces* the value to assign to the attribute. I would use a separate class method to keep the two pieces of code separate.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


class MyList(list):
    pass


@dataclass
class Struct:
    field: MyList

    @classmethod
    def from_iterable(cls, x):
        return cls(MyList(x))


s1 = Struct(MyList([1,2,3]))
s2 = Struct.from_iterable((4,5,6))
```

Now, you *only* pass an existing value of `MyList` to `Struct.__init__`. Tuples, lists, and whatever else `MyList` can accept are passed to `Struct.from_iterable` instead, which will take care of constructing the `MyList` instance to pass to `Struct`.

Comment: This is the approach that Rust takes, and if I were designing a Python program from scratch, I may attempt this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a Pydantic BaseModel instead of a dataclass?

With the following code, my Pycharm does not complain:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyList(list):
    pass


class PydanticStruct(BaseModel):
    field: MyList

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.field = MyList(self.field)


a = PydanticStruct(field=['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: I'm not actively developing new Python code or this project anymore, but I'll look into Pydantic if I ever do work on Python again.

Answer (score 0):

`dataclasses` works best in straight-forward data containers, advanced utilities like conversion were consciously ommitted (see [here](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/issues/60#issuecomment-341330376) for a complete writeup of this and similar features). Implementing this is a fair bit of work, since it should also include the pycharm plugin that notices in how far conversion would be supported now.

A much better approach would be to use one of the 3rd party that already did this, the most popular one being [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/), probably because it has the easiest [migration for dataclasses](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/).

---

A native `pydantic` solution could look like this, where the conversion code is part of `MyList`. Handling it that way makes the `__post_init__` unnecessary, leading to cleaner model definitions:

```
import pydantic


class MyList(list):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        """Validators handle data validation, as well as data conversion.

        This function yields validator functions, with the last-yielded
        result being the final value of a pydantic field annotated with
        this class's type.
        Since we inherit from 'list', our constructor already supports
        building 'MyList' instances from iterables - if we didn't, we 
        would need to write that code by hand and yield it instead.
        """
        yield cls


class Struct(pydantic.BaseModel):
    field: MyList  # accepts any iterable as input


print(Struct(field=(1, 2, 3)))
# prints: field=[1, 2, 3]
```